# Open file with user input (string) - C

Tags: c, file

I'm trying to figure out how user input can be used as a filename in C. Here's the simple program I wrote.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 100

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char name[MAX];


    printf("Enter filename: ");
    fgets(name, MAX, stdin);

    if((fp = fopen(name, "w")) == 0)
        printf("File cannot be opened!");

    return 0;
}
```

It always prints "File cannot be opened".

Comment: Do you have permission to create files in the current working directory?

Comment: Yes. Matt Eckert was right about fgets. I tried with scanf and it works.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `fgets` before attempting to use it?

Comment: No I didn't. I'm a beginner and I'm trying to learn.

Comment: The fact that you are a beginner means you should read _more_ documentation, not less.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`fgets` retains the newline in the input.

Comment: I tried with "scanf("%s", name) and it works! Is scanf the only correct way to do it?

Comment: You can replace the newline in the string from `fgets` with a null character. Be wary of using `scanf` for input: http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Answer (score 1):

here's a function that you'll have to add after the fgets to slove this problem

```
void newlineRemover(char *array)
{
    int i , lenght ;
    lenght = strlen(array);
    for(i = 0 ; i < lenght ; i++)
     {
        if(array[i] == '\n')
            array[i] = '\0' ;
     }
}
```

Comment: Your function is broken: `array[i] == '\0'` should be `array[i] = '\0'`.

Comment: You should start at the end of the array, rather than traversing the whole array until reaching the end of it just to remove 1 char. Your for loop could do for (i=lenght; i > 0; i--)... your code will be faster this way.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add ".txt" extension and then it will work.
The following program opens a txt file in the same directory as the name of the following date:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char a[1000000],s[20];
    strcpy(s,__DATE__);
    int i,j,k,l;
    strcat(s,".txt");
    printf("%s",s);
    FILE *f,*ff;
    f=fopen(s,"w");
}
```