# File is not being opened when inputted. C

Tags: file, null, fopen, do-while

My issue is when I try to input spath as the first parameter for fopen(); is keeps looping wether the file exists or not. Yet, when i hard code the parameter to my test file it works properly.I am not sure what the issue is, maybe it is the syntax.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char spath[255], dpath[255];
  int c;
  FILE *sfp, *dfp;

  do
  {
     printf("Please enter a source file:\n");
     fgets(spath, sizeof(spath), stdin);
     if(strlen(spath) > 253)
     {
     while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
     }
  }while((sfp=fopen(spath,"r")) == NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon further reading, fgets() has a new line character in the array which messes things up. To fix this use:

```
  for(i = 0 ; i < lenght ; i++) 
  { 
  if(array[i] == '\n') 
  array[i] = '\0' ; 
  }
```

This takes away the new line character and insert a terminator character.
Click this link for further information: [Open file with user input (string) - C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16895390/open-file-with-user-input-string-c)