# How do you open a text file inputted from the user on C

Tags: c, text-files, user-input

I just started learning C and I am trying to get this type of code:

```
Enter text file: cat.txt
```

Then when it runs it should display all the text but if it is not a valid text file it should throw an error

Comment: What about reading C courses? Get input text from console, open, read, print file content is very basic and should be found in many examples. By the way what is a "valid text file"? It will depend on text encoding… In pure ASCII text you can check bounds of each characters (see ASCII docs), but in − let say − utf-8 it is far more complex, and then you should check for UTF8 format docs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   char ch, file_name[25];
   FILE *fp;

   printf("Enter the name of file you wish to see\n");
   gets(file_name);

   fp = fopen(file_name,"r"); // read mode

   if( fp == NULL )
   {
      perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   printf("The contents of %s file are :\n", file_name);

   while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF )
      printf("%c",ch);

   fclose(fp);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: ***DON'T. USE. GETS***. Even the man page explicitly advises **against** its usage!

Comment: @cad Not against but _removed_  :-)

Comment: what would you advise to use instead of gets

Comment: see this may be usefull
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16895390/open-file-with-user-input-string-c